# I can't use std::vector of auto_ptr - should i use shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I don't really need to share the objects, but i do want to make sure no memory leakage occurs.
Is it correct to use shared_ptr in this case?

Comment: Are the objects stored in the vector allocated dynamically? Do they have to be?

Answer (score 7):

If you are using boost, [boost::ptr_vector](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html) might be better suited for your needs.

If not, then you can either use `shared_ptr` as you suggested or manually delete the elements of the vector once you are done with them.

From maintenance point of view, `shared_ptr` would be the preferred solution. Note, however, that `shared_ptr` can bring some performance penalties, which may or may not be significant for your application.

Answer (score 4):

If low-level performance/ memory usage are not critical requirements (ie 97% of all cases) then just go with shared_ptr. It's straightforward and well understood.

If you really want to keep things tight and/ or express the ownership intention more precisely then [boost::ptr_vector](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html) might be better - but if your class doesn't manage any other memory then just manually deleting in your destructor is not as big a sin as we're sometimes led to believe ;-) I'm a big RAII proponent, but still do this from time to time.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit of an overkill, but there isn't a much better smart pointer for that. You might also consider boost's pointer containers.

In C++0x you'd be able to store `std::unique_ptr` in containers, which is closer to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Boost.PointerContainer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html). Using a `shared_ptr` expresses shared ownership. Now if you are sure, that your objects are bound to the lifetime of the container, then a [PointerContainer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html) is the better option design-wise (is that even a word?).